# Do Winsock blocking calls return after completing APC?

Tags: c, winsock2

MSDN documentation for, i.e., `recv` function [states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as recv, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread.

Documentation for some other functions that perform alertable wait, i.e. [`GetOverlappedResultEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh448542(v=vs.85).aspx), states that they **return** after executing one or more APC with error code WAIT_IO_COMPLETION.

However, about i.e. `recv` function this isn't explicitly stated. Also, there is no error code for this function that correspond to being "waked" on APC.

Thus there is a question in the title: do Winsock blocking calls return after completing APC? Or they behave differently from "other" alertable waits in the sense that after APC they return to wait state?

Comment: This is news to me.  I had no idea that recv() did any more than block until data is received, the connection is closed or some error occurs.  Has anyone actually seen the behaviour described, ie. an APC being executed while recv() waits?

Answer (score -1):

Winsock, and socket blocking calls in general, will return immediately if buffered data is available on the socket.  If no data is immediately available, the blocking function obviously enters the alertable state.

Comment: My question is what happens when there is no data, and alertable state is interrupted by APC. Do these calls go back to wait state or return like other wait functions. Your reply does not answer that.